# Jenkins authentication fails with GitLab

Tags: ssl, nginx, jenkins, gitlab

Before to say my problem, I have installed my **git-lab**(omnibus setting) and git-lab is connected external **nginx** server. And than now I am setting Jenkins.

While I am making new Jenkins item, when I select "Git" in "Source code management" I receive following message in the picture.[git selecting screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGU72.png)

So I checked `error.log` in my external **nginx**. And then I found following error code.

**`[error] 20979#0: OCSP_basic_verify() failed (SSL: error:27069076:OCSP routines:OCSP_basic_verify:signer certificate not found) while requesting certificate status, responder: ocsp.int-x1.letsencrypt.org`**

I also searched it on google and anywhere I know, but I still don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkins server certificate verification failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36911186/jenkins-server-certificate-verification-failed)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with adding your credentials?

Select the Git option in Source Code Management.Fill out the Repository url.
click on Add option below the Repository Url. Add the Username and Password.Save it and select the added credentials from the drop down.